# PHP headers always give error Undefined Index even using $_SERVER global

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am performing an ajax request cross domain. I have been trying to use functions that return the headers in an array only to find that I get Undefined Index even though I can return their values in my ajax request and print them the screen.

I have found some posts on SO that said I should be using $_SERVER globals. So I switched to that method only to get the same results.

Here is my jQuery:

```
setTimeout(function() {
                jQuery.ajax({
                    url: 'http://something.com',    
                    type:"POST",
                    dataType:"json",
                    crossDomain:true,
                    contentType:"application/json",
                    data: jsonData,
                    processData:false,
                    cache:false,
                    beforeSend: function( xhr ) {
                        xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization",api_key[index]);
                        xhr.setRequestHeader("Action","PUSH");
                    },
                    success: function(data) {
                        alert(data.action);
                        alert(data.platform + ' : ' + data.message + ' : ' +  data.app_name );

                        if(data.message == 'success') 
                        {
                            jQuery('#hollmanPNs_send_push div#hollmanPNs_progressbar' + index).progressbar("value",100);

                            //add message to the paragraph for app name
                            jQuery('#hollmanPNs_send_push p#hollmanPNs_paragraph' + index).append(': Complete'); 
                        }
                    },
                    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        alert( 'We had an error: ' + textStatus + errorThrown );
                    }
                }).fail(function() {
                    alert( 'We had a failed AJAX call.');
                });//end ajax

            }, index * 5000);//end timeout function
```

And here is what I am using for PHP:

```
if($_SERVER['HTTP_ACTION'] != '')
{
//Do Something
}
```

I have tried switching to:

```
xhr.setRequestHeader("X-Action","PUSH");
```

and

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_X_ACTION']
```

with the same results. Only I was not able to return them to my ajax request.

I am using PHP 5.3.3.

I am also using this function which I change depending on the different headers I am trying at the time:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Action, Authorization, Content-Type');
```

Comment: Not values are populated everytime.

Comment: I assumed this created a custom header value. But I still have the problems with the others as well.

Comment: Dump `$_SERVER` and see what you get

Comment: I can't get that back as I am performing an ajax request... unless you know how I can do that. I can get back individual variables, and I have, but I can't use them in PHP otherwise I get Undefined Index.

Comment: @Cedric put `var_dump($_SERVER); die();` as the first thing in your PHP script, make a request. Then look at the response of that AJAX request in the Network panel of your Chrome dev tools.

Comment: @KevinNagurski with Chrome I saw nothing for header "Action", but when I changed it to "X-Action" it showed "PUSH".

Comment: @Cedric yes, but what does the actual var_dump look like in the response part of the request look like?

Comment: @KevinNagurski When I went to use the variable in PHP I still get Undefined index: HTTP_X_ACTION.

Comment: @Cedric but what does the var_dump show?

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to get the headers a different way like so:

```
$headers = getallheaders();

if(array_key_exists('Action', $headers) && $headers['Action'] != '')
{
//Do Something
}
```

Comment: I tried this as well as apache_request_headers() function. Same problem, that is why I switched to the $_SERVER global in hopes that would fix the issue.

Comment: I updated my code, you don't want to include the HTTP portion. Just `var_dump($headers);` so you can see what headers came through.

Comment: I haven't been able to return a dump in my ajax request to see what all shows up. I have been able to return the variable and see that it is set to "PUSH", but I can't use it in the PHP without getting an Undefined Index.

Comment: consider using [POSTMAN](http://getpostman.com), it will help you immensely in getting your ajax calls tested.

Comment: The ajax works perfectly, just not the headers on the PHP side. I will consider your recommendation.

Comment: I would find it very unlikely that the code I posted to you above would not work considering the code you've posted above. As well if you're using chrome just press F12 and look at the raw response from your request, which would also allow you to see the `var_dump`

Comment: I tried to put the dump in my error log file, but it printed nothing. I also tried viewing the console in safari and I don't get any response using the var_dump.

Comment: nothing...  When I print_r() it returns 1, if that helps.

Comment: what do you get with `var_dump($_SERVER);` then

Comment: what does this do? `file_put_contents('server.txt', print_r($_SERVER, true));` The `$_SERVER` variable should always have something in it.

Comment: Okay that returned everything including: [HTTP_X_AUTHORIZATION] => k8rpY7KtV8G9jF5n -- and -- [HTTP_X_ACTION] => PUSH

Comment: and doing this, it should also work. `$headers = getallheaders(); file_put_contents('server.txt', print_r($headers, true));`

Comment: Yes, I was able to get both the "[X-Action] => PUSH " and "[X-Authorization] => k8rpY7KtV8G9jF5n"

Comment: So then my code above provided should work then, of course changing the header from 'Action' to 'X-Action'

Comment: Everything works, but I still get "PHP Notice:  Undefined index: X-Action on line 316" which is this "if($headers['X-Action'] != '')"